# How to make program reset back to the beginning with a loop

Tags: java, loops, user-interface, button, text

I have a simple money conversion program that allows the user to enter in one of three textfields in order to have their amount be converted into USD. I want the user to be able to enter information as many times as they want, so I've created a `JButton` called `continueButton`, but I'm having trouble making loop correctly and reset the program.

**Question: How can I write a loop statement to make this program start at the beginning, allowing the user to enter numbers again?**

```
public class MoneyConversionPanel extends JPanel {

    JLabel yenLabel = new JLabel();
    JLabel poundLabel = new JLabel();
    JLabel euroLabel = new JLabel();
    JTextField yenText = new JTextField("Enter Yen amount here:");
    JTextField poundText = new JTextField("Enter Pound amount here:");
    JTextField euroText = new JTextField("Enter Euro amount here:");
    JButton continueButton = new JButton("Click to reset");
    JButton yenButton = new JButton("Convert");
    JButton poundButton = new JButton("Convert");
    JButton euroButton = new JButton ("Convert");
    MoneyConversion userInput;

    public MoneyConversionPanel()
    {

    Dimension dimension = new Dimension(1200,1000);

    setPreferredSize(dimension);

    setBackground(Color.cyan);

    yenButton.addActionListener(new buttonListener());

    add(yenLabel);
    add(poundLabel);
    add(euroLabel);
    add(yenText);
    add(poundText);
    add(continueButton);
    continueButton.setVisible(false);
    add(euroText);
    add(yenButton);
    add(poundButton);
    add(euroButton);

}

    private class buttonListener implements ActionListener
    {
        double conversionDouble;
        NumberFormat costFmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();


        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    do {

        for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
        if(e.getSource() == yenButton)

        {
            userInput = new MoneyConversion(Double.parseDouble(yenText.getText()));
            conversionDouble = userInput.convertYen();
            yenLabel.setText("" + costFmt.format(conversionDouble));
            continueButton.setVisible(true);
        }

        else if(e.getSource() == poundButton)
        {
            userInput = new MoneyConversion(Double.parseDouble(poundText.getText()));
            conversionDouble = userInput.convertPounds();
            poundLabel.setText("" + costFmt.format(conversionDouble));
            continueButton.setVisible(true);
        }

        else if(e.getSource() == euroButton)
        {
            userInput = new MoneyConversion(Double.parseDouble(euroText.getText()));
            conversionDouble = userInput.convertEuro();
            euroLabel.setText("" + costFmt.format(conversionDouble));
            continueButton.setVisible(true);
        }
        }

    } while(e.getSource() == continueButton);
        } 

        }

}
```

Comment: can you narrow down to the section that you are asking the question ?

Comment: Get rid of the do-while loop as it is tying up your Swing event thread. This is not how you want to do event-driven programming. Instead, why even have a "continue" button? Just don't end the program until they're done. And no, don't "start with a while loop" as @Jonjongot suggests -- that's just as bad and again will not work for an event-driven program.

Comment: I'm specifically referring to the bottom of the section where the actionPerformed body is.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels ok. just saying. i didnt even read the whole post -_-

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, so how would I go about making this GUI allow the user to enter as many times as he/she wants?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestions:

- Use just one JTextField input window.
- Prompt with a JLabel to the left of this window.
- Have either three conversion JButtons, one for each currency
- Or one conversion JButton and 3 JRadioButtons to allow the user to select which currency to convert to.
- There's no need to loop or reset. Just simply do the conversion and display it each time the button is pressed -- that's it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I was just overthinking it with the loops.

Comment: @Jordan: You're welcome. It's sometimes hard to shift gears, to go all of a sudden from linear console programs over to event-driven GUI's, but once you learn the basic concepts, they're yours for ever.

Comment: Apart from this maybe @Jordan can set text field empty after the calculation! That will look better! Simply `someTextField.setText("");`

Comment: @user3248168: that could work nicely, thanks for the suggestion. Or  if he wants the option of keeping the number but converting to another number, he could use a FocusListener and call `selectAll()` on the JTextfield on `focusGained()` to make it easy to change the text if desired.

Comment: Yeah that would look more user friendly! but might be little tough! :)